# Alignment of div elements at center and right

Tags: html, css

I have four tabs developed with HTML5/CSS3/JS shown below.

[image]

I have used `display:inline-block;` for tab divs and `text-align:center` for their parent div to locate all four tabs at the center of the page.

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='tabItem'>YOU</div>
    <div class='tabItem'>DATABASE</div>
    <div class='tabItem'>TASKS</div>
    <div class='tabItem'>HELP</div>
</div>
```

CSS3:

```
.parent{text-align:center;}
.tabItem{display:inline-block;}
```

Now I want to locate two of the tabs i.e. YOU and HELP at the right-side of the page, and the rest of the tabs i.e. DATABASE and TASKS at the center of the page. I wonder how I can do that.

It's preferred to have div elements follow the natural flow of the page.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt e.g. as a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) and not just some code snippets...

Comment: See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cz1tn1zm/

Comment: with `.parent{text-align:center;}` all your child divs will be centered. Do you want  `YOU` and `HELP` to be aligned on the right? Please give a clear description of what you want

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this

```css
.parent{text-align:center;}
.tabItem{display:inline-block;}
.right{float:right;}
.left{float:left;}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='tabItem left'>Content for Left</div>
    <div class='tabItem'>DATABASE</div>
    <div class='tabItem'>TASKS</div>
    <div class='tabItem right'>YOU</div>
    <div class='tabItem right'>HELP</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is your solution!

```css
.parent{text-align:center;}
.tabItem{display:inline-block;}
.right {
float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent center'>
    <div class='tabItem'>DATABASE</div>
    <div class='tabItem'>TASKS</div>
      <div class='parent right'>
        <div class='tabItem'>YOU</div>
        <div class='tabItem'>HELP</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps!!

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
        .parent{text-align:center;}
        .tabItem{display:inline-block;}
        #right {float: right;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='parent'>
        <div class='tabItem'>DATABASE</div>
        <div class='tabItem'>TASKS</div>
        <div id="right" class='tabItem'>YOU</div>
        <div id="right" class='tabItem'>HELP</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Or just put those two divs in a parent container and give it an id="right" to avoid repeating id !!

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to set the tabs you need to relocate to absolute position, so they will be out of the normal content flow, then you can truly center the other two tabs.

```css
.parent {
  background: pink;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.tabItem {
  margin: 0 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: aqua;
}
.tabItem:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px; /* width of "HELP" tab */
}
.tabItem:nth-child(4) {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='tabItem'>YOU</div>
  <div class='tabItem'>DATABASE</div>
  <div class='tabItem'>TASKS</div>
  <div class='tabItem'>HELP</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 feature `display:flex` is an option too. Can play around with it to see if it would work.

```css
.parent{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
}

.item{
    padding: 10px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

.right{
    margin-left:auto;
}

.left{
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="item left">you</div>
    <div class="item">database</div>
    <div class="item">tasks</div>
    <div class="item right">help</div>
</div>
```